# Sony Bravia Unsupported Signal After Turning Off Display

Tags: graphics, hdmi

Installed 12.04 over a previous hackintosh build a couple days ago and trying to iron out all the kinks. The most frustrating right now is my HDTV output through HDMI to a Sony Bravia KDL-40BX421.

The output through HDMI works when I start up. However most times when I turn off the display and turn it back on I get a "Unsupported Device, Please check your device output" error on the tv. Unplugging the HDMI cable from the back of the computer resets the problem.

My mb is a Z68M-D2H and I'm running an i3-2105 with HD3000 graphics. If I run xrandr and turn the other outputs off, the problem seems to happen less but it still occurs.

Here is the output for xrandr:

```
    Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1600mm x 900mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1280x720       60.0  
   640x480        60.0  
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I really appreciate any help on this thanks.

Comment: I have a similar problem - did you ever solve it ?

Comment: I have the same issue with Debian and my solution it to switch to virtual console 1 (Ctrl-Alt-F1) for a moment and back to GUI:  Alt-Left_Arrow